# Laravel 5.4 how to assign roles to user by form request?

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, roles, eloquent

i have a users list & here i put a option to assign role to each users, for that when click 'Add Role' link it will show this route

```
Route::get('admin/home/role/{user}', 'RoleController@create');
```

in create function my form code is...

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('admin/home/role') }}">
  {{ csrf_field()   }}


   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="role" class="form-control" >
      <option value="1"> Admin </option>
      <option value="2"> Editor</option>
    </select>
   </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Role
    </button>
  </form>
```

to manage this form my POST route is...

```
Route::post('admin/home/role', 'RoleController@store');
```

now how to insert this form request data into role_user table? oh! i have already 3 table, users, roles & role_user.

User model relationship code is...

```
 public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
}
```

Role model relationship code is...

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'role_user');
}
```

my question is how to insert form request data into role_user table?
i know one way that is...

```
public function store(Request $request, User $user)
{

    $role = Role::find(1);
    $user = User::find(19);

    $role->user()->attach($user);


}
```

it works, but this is not dynamic. How to insert by form request? please help me. I searching about this topic tutorial but not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to send `Role id` and `user id`  value to store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $user_id=$request->input('user_id'); // get user id from post request
     $role_id=$request->input('role_id'); // get  Role id from post request

      /* Todo request validation*/


    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $role = Role::find($role_id);


    $user->roles()->attach($role);
}
```

view :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ action('RoleController@store') }}">
  {{ csrf_field()   }}
  <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}" /> // you need to pass $user to this view  
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="role_id" class="form-control" >
      <option value="1"> Admin </option>
      <option value="2"> Editor</option>
    </select>
   </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add Role
    </button>
  </form>
```

Comment: it says new error. which is...                                                                      FatalThrowableError in RoleController.php line 45:
Call to a member function roles() on null

Comment: rename your public function role() in user model to  public function roles()

Comment: be sure of this :    $user->roles()->attach($role);

Comment: $user->roles()->attach($role);   it is & User model function is                                  public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_user');
    }

Comment: problem is here...        $user_id=$request->input('user')   $role_id=$request->input('role');     this input name was user_id  & role_id now change it with form name user & role now it works . tnx Jafar

Comment: one more question please. what will be update method when i wanna change user role? then what will be  $user->roles()->attach($role); this line ?

Comment: $user->roles()->attach($role); //for add ...$user->roles()->detach($role); /to delete

Comment: yup i know detach for delete, but what is update method? when i will change role admin to editor then it works like a create method, it created new row into table, i just want to update that

Comment: you can use updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes); but here you don't have any extra field in pivot table ...to do this you need delete all by useing detach() and after delete you can attach($new_role);